# Why can't I render this angularJS code?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, zingchart

This code is taken from the following tutorial using ZingChart.
http://www.zingchart.com/blog/2015/03/05/zingchart-angularjs/

My Code looks like the following:

```
//my-zingchart.html
<html ng-app="myApp">
<head>
   <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.min.js">
   <script src="http://cdn.zingchart.com/zingchart.min.js">
   <script src="node_modules/zingchart-angularjs/src/zingchart-angularjs.js">
   <script>
       var app = angular.module('myApp',['zingchart-angularjs']);

        app.controller('MainController', function($scope){
        $scope.myData = [1,4,5,5,10];
});
   </script>
</head>
<body>
 <div ng-controller="MainController">
<zingchart id="chart-1" zc-values="myData"></zingchart>
</div>
 </body>
</html>
```

When I try to render this in chrome, I get nothing but a blank page, and the following error:

> Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.14/$injector/modulerr?p0=myApp&p1=Error%3A%…gleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.3.14%2Fangular.min.js%3A17%3A381)

I've looked for similar errors, but their solutions don't seem to fix my problem.

Comment: start by making sure the zingchart angular module is loading

Comment: @inorganik, how can I make sure the module is loading?

Comment: Use development version of angular to get more verbose error output and stack trace. Minified version creates links like that where you have to go to their site to interpret it more

Comment: look in browser dev tools network to be sure path is correct and file is even loading

Comment: @charlietfl Thanks, the path was fine

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Close your Script tags!

```
<html ng-app="myApp">
<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://cdn.zingchart.com/zingchart.min.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/zingchart-angularjs/src/zingchart-angularjs.js"></script>
    <script>
        var app = angular.module('myApp', ['zingchart-angularjs']);

        app.controller('MainController', function ($scope) {
            $scope.myData = [1, 4, 5, 5, 10];
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div ng-controller="MainController">
        <zingchart id="chart-1" zc-values="myData"></zingchart>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Result

[image: Now working]